# Pyplot not plotting marker for detected peaks

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy

I'm writing a Python script that plots a candlestick chart of with x markers indicating peak candlesticks. The used data is a series of USD/JPY rates read using `pandas.read_csv()` from a csv file provided by Oanda API. The result of `pandas.DataFrame.head()` is as follows:

```
                  time    close     open     high      low  volume
0  2016/08/19 06:00:00  100.256   99.919  100.471   99.887   30965
1  2016/08/22 06:00:00  100.335  100.832  100.944  100.221   32920
2  2016/08/23 06:00:00  100.253  100.339  100.405   99.950   26069
3  2016/08/24 06:00:00  100.460  100.270  100.619  100.104   22340
4  2016/08/25 06:00:00  100.546  100.464  100.627  100.314   17224
```

While the candlestick chart itself is displayed properly (although it needs some foramtting), I don't see any markers on it.

[image]

What I expect is something like an example graph output shown on the [scipy.signal.find_peaks document](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html), only it is a candlestick chart instead of a line graph.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import mpl_finance

df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1])

opens = df['open']
highs = df['high']
lows = df['low']
closes = df['close']
indices = find_peaks(highs)[0]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

mpl_finance.candlestick2_ohlc(ax1, opens, highs, lows, closes, width=4, colorup='k', colordown='r', alpha=0.75)
ax1.plot(x=indices, y=[highs[j] for j in indices], fmt="x", label="peak highs")

ax1.grid()

plt.show()
```

I suspected it's either the x or y parameter of ax1.plot() being empty, which is shown otherwise using pdb debugger:

```
-> ax1.plot(x=indices, y=[highs[j] for j in indices], fmt="x", label="peak highs")
(Pdb) indices
array([  1,  10,  15,  18,  23,  25,  29,  34,  39,  47,  50,  59,  66,
        70,  74,  76,  78,  81,  84,  87,  92,  95,  99, 101, 107, 113,
       118, 126, 130, 138, 143, 145, 158, 161, 164, 170, 172, 176, 182,
       186, 196, 203, 208, 215, 220, 222, 226, 230, 233, 237, 241, 246,
       248, 256, 261, 263, 267, 282, 286, 290, 293, 296, 304, 306, 308,
       310, 313, 316, 322, 331, 336, 342, 349, 352, 359, 367, 369, 373,
       378, 382, 391, 395, 400, 403, 405, 411, 416, 422, 425, 428, 438,
       441, 444, 447, 450, 454, 459, 466, 471, 473, 477, 485, 493, 497],
      dtype=int32)
(Pdb) [highs[j] for j in indices]
[100.944, 104.33, 103.07, 103.367, 102.79799999999999, 101.258, 101.851, 104.17399999999999, 104.64299999999999, 104.882, 105.544, 106.95700000000001, 111.375, 113.911, 114.837, 114.78399999999999, 114.415, 116.134, 118.676, 118.251, 117.822, 118.624, 117.54299999999999, 116.89, 115.634, 115.38600000000001, 113.538, 114.962, 113.787, 114.765, 115.512, 115.2, 112.213, 111.48, 111.587, 109.23299999999999, 109.5, 111.79, 113.05799999999999, 114.39299999999999, 112.135, 111.721, 110.823, 111.8, 112.47399999999999, 112.935, 113.696, 114.505, 113.583, 112.429, 112.21600000000001, 110.99, 111.05799999999999, 110.95700000000001, 109.833, 109.85600000000001, 110.678, 112.72399999999999, 113.264, 113.20200000000001, 113.446, 112.834, 113.589, 114.10700000000001, 114.25, 114.462, 114.288, 114.742, 113.91799999999999, 111.70100000000001, 113.095, 113.758, 113.64399999999999, 113.398, 113.39299999999999, 111.49, 111.23200000000001, 109.77799999999999, 110.491, 109.79, 107.912, 107.685, 106.47, 107.06200000000001, 107.305, 106.65, 107.01799999999999, 107.499, 107.405, 107.788, 109.552, 110.044, 109.406, 110.02600000000001, 110.461, 111.40299999999999, 109.84899999999999, 110.275, 110.85799999999999, 110.91, 110.765, 111.14399999999999, 112.80799999999999, 113.18700000000001]
```

Could anyone give me a possible solution or an explanation of the cause?

Comment: I don't have time to test thoroughly, but what happens if you just plot the peaks  without the candlesticks? And what if you were to change the format of the peaks so they would be more visible (for example `fmt='go-'`)

Comment: @DizietAsahi I tried both but still don't see the markers. The former gave me an empty graph only with axes, labels, and a grid, and the latter produced a plain candlestick chart.